# How to ignore missing glyphs in font used by PDFBox 2.0.7

Tags: java, pdf, exception, fonts, pdfbox

I'm seeing "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+05D0 in font" (as an example) exception being thrown when calling the showText(String) method of PDFPageContentStream.

Catching the exception isn't very helpful because good characters won't get written. Neither is checking each character in the input string, which would be a performance killer (each PDF could be thousands of pages, millions of characters). What I really need is a way to prevent the exception for ANY missing glyph and have it automatically replaced with some other glyph, or a dynamically created glyph that shows the unicode value.

I don't want to stop producing the PDF because a font doesn't support a particular glyph, I just want some replacement character to be used instead and keep going.

How to achieve this?

Comment: *"Catching the exception isn't very helpful because good characters won't get written. Neither is checking each character in the input string, which would be a performance killer"* - if you get that exception only rarely, you could combine those methods: catch the exception, and in the catch block check the input string characters, replace accordingly, and draw the (now modified) string again.

Comment: that been said, if you programmed that *checking each character in the input string* in a good manner, it would not be a performance killer.

Comment: _"I just want some replacement character"_ so this will result people with unusual characters in their names (e.g. Miško Hevery) receiving PDFs where their name is like this "Mi?ko Hevery". I doubt you client may want that.

Comment: mkl, thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, that’s still not going to work well enough. Is it possible to specify a hierarchy of fonts? That way, I could use the customer selected font for Latin / Extended Latin and a second known font as a fallback for the missing glyphs. Possible?

Comment: My solution was to force the use of a font that contains the necessary glyphs. However, this is a poor solution. I will have to file a feature request with the PDFBox project that they support a font chain where the primary font is used unless a glyph is missing, then an alternate font is selected in the font chain for the missing glyph; if no font contains the glyph, then a substitute glyph (possibly containing the unicode value) is rendered in the document. Throwing an exception in this case does not promote the development of a quality application.

Comment: @Scott Your font chain idea sounds perfect.  Was your idea ever submitted as a feature request to the project?  If so, I'd like to see the status and/or vote for it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did

```
private final char[] replacements = IntStream.range(0, 1<<16)
    .map(c -> canRender(font, c) ? c : "?")
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
             StringBuilder::append)
    .toString().toCharArray();

// This is extremely ugly!!!
private boolean canRender(PDType0Font font, int codepoint) {
    try {
        font.getStringWidth(new String(Character.toChars(codepoint)));
        return true;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

String sanitize(String input) {
    return input.codePoints()
            .map(c -> c<replacements.length ? replacements[c] : '?')
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
                     StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
```

I don't think, it's worth optimizing as during the PDF generation, more work has to be done, including the `hasGlyph` tests.