# How to find out what chars can be rendered in PDF in the given font?

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

I have got a problem like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46439548/581205): Some characters can't be shown in the font I'm using (`Lato-Regular.ttf`). The font is gets loaded via

```
document = new PDDocument();
baseFont = PDType0Font.load(document, stream);
```

In a comment, I was told that type 0 fonts are long obsolete, however, the Javadoc of `PDTrueTypeFont#load` says

> Simple fonts only support 256 characters. For Unicode support, use `PDType0Font#load(PDDocument, File)` instead.

which is what I did.

---

The problem happened with `\u0090`, which is actually a control character, so there's obviously no point in rendering it. The primary cause was a wrong charset used in an import.

The font seems to contain all characters I needed so far. *However, there may be some proper characters missing in the font as the input is an arbitrary Unicode string.*

The replacement of invalid chars is trivial, but I need to know which chars are valid. Initially, I thought, I could use

```
PDType0Font.hasGlyph(code);
```

but the code is some PDF-internal code, i.e., completely useless when you have a String and no idea how to convert. There's a protected method `encode`, which "Encodes the given string for use in a PDF content stream" (whatever it means) and nothing else sounding like a conversion.

*Is there a better way than this ugliness?*

```
private boolean canRender(PDType0Font font, int codepoint) {
    try {
        font.getStringWidth(new String(Character.toChars(codepoint)));
        return true;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is using reflection more ugly or less ugly in your eyes?

Comment: @mkl I guess, reflection is less ugly and faster than catching a few thousands exceptions.

Comment: I suspect this is some kind of legacy terminology, but: type 0 fonts were deprecated in favour of opentype almost 20 years ago, so what version of the PDF spec do your documents conform to? (because that detail makes a _huge_ difference wrt possible solutions here).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm using `Lato-Regular.ttf` and loading it via `PDType0Font#load`. I don't think that the font is obsolete, but maybe it should be loaded using something else - no idea, two years ago I tried this and it worked. `+++` What version of the spec? No idea, I'm using `new PDDocument()` to create it and never specified any version. `+++` Don't get me wrong, but I was tasked to generate a PDF document using the above font, nothing else. We tested that it works in all major viewers and that's it. I'm very ignorant about PDF.

Comment: I was confused by your "Some characters can't be shown in the Type 0 font I'm using" since type0 is internal to PDF, but I guess that's just PDFBox having poor naming for its methods. Does any of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092183/understanding-loading-of-font-in-pdfbox-2-0 apply here? (It might be worth updating your post to show _how_ you're making your PDF, so that people can spot whether or not there's some step that's obvious to experienced users that is completely unintuitive to if you're new to it)

Comment: Having said that, in order to prevent an XY problem]() back and forth, it might also be worth adding some text that explains what you're trying to ultimately achieve. Right now your question suggests you're trying to compile a PDF despite the font you're using not supporting (all of) the text you're encoding, so that's... curious? Why not make sure you have a custom font by merging Lato with some fallback that fills in the gaps that you know Lato itself has, and then making sure the PDF loads that massive font with subsetting turned on?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've edited the question. Some more comments: The "type 0" thing is confusing. • There's nothing special in my document creation, just a default constructor call. • The font used contains everything I needed so far, but I want to prevent future problems as what gets rendered are user data, i.e., an arbitrary Unicode string. • No idea about merging fonts, there's probably no need.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Type 0 fonts are not deprecated, where did you read that?

Comment: @maaartinus The default version produced by PDFBox is 1.4. But this can be changed if needed. No there is no better way than this uglyness.

Answer (score 0):

> The replacement of invalid chars is trivial, but I need to know which chars are valid.

Use [`Font.canDisplayUpto(text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplayUpTo-java.lang.String-)

```
String content = "ĈĉĜĝĤĥĴĵŜŝŬŭ";
java.awt.Font font = java.awt.Font.createFont​(java.awt.TRUETYPE_FONT,
                                              inputStream);
int index = font.canDisplayUpTo​(content);
if (index != -1) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(
        String.format("Font does not contain U+%06X: %s",
             context.codePointAt(index),
             font.getFamily()));
}
```

For loading TRUETYPE_FONT and TYPE1_FONT are possible. Type0 might possibly not covered, but you mentioned True-Type compatibility.

Comment: Unfortunately, `canDisplayUpTo` seems to be the solution for `java.awt.Font`, but `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont` is unrelated.

Comment: @maaartinus that's why the package path for this Font. However the java.awt.Font may be created from an InputStream too. I'll add it to the code.

Comment: @maaartinus Type-0 might be the problem.

Comment: The [font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato) is not old and it's named `*.ttf`. Loading font as `PDType0Font` seems to be the recommended way for all fonts, whenever you want more than 256 chars. The whole pdfbox confuses me. Your solution may work - I'll try it.